# How to use case keyword in scala functions?

Tags: scala

I am getting confused with the use of `case` keyword in function body of scala.
How to correct the below and what is the use of `case` here?

```
val fun=(x:Int,y:Int)=>{case(a,b)=>a+b}
```

Comment: Why you even want to use `case`? You already have the two variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the `case` is totally unnecessary. Just do

```scala
val fun = (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y
```

`case` can be used to write a certain flavor of shorthand for anonymous functions when the compiler already has some idea of what types it expects. E.g. if you are trying to construct an anonymous function to pass as an argument to some other function (e.g. a List's `map`), or when you've given an explicit type hint when declaring your function as a `val`.

```scala
// explicit type hint for what `fun` is supposed to be
val fun: (Int, Int) => Int = { case (a, b) => a + b }
fun(1, 2) // returns 3

// no explicit type hint, the compiler can't figure out what type a and b are
val f = { case (a, b) => a + b }
        ^
error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?

// passing a function as an argument where a `(Int, Int) => A` is expected
val listOfTuples = List(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6)
listOfTuples.map { case (a, b) => a + b }
// returns List(3, 7, 11)
```

Another way to understand it is that it's like a shorthand for doing a `match` block on the argument to the function, e.g.

```scala
def addTupleParts(tup: (Int, Int)) = tup match {
  case (a, b) => a + b
}
listOfTuples.map(addTupleParts)
listOfTuples.map { case (a, b) => a + b }
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but to add: `case` initiates a pattern match. `case (a, b)` will match a tuple of two elements and not two parameters of the function in the question -- as written, the case is expecting a single tuple parameter.

Comment: True, though the scala compiler seems to let you treat a function that takes two arguments as a function that takes a Tuple2, when you try using `case` (though that might depend on which specific version of `scalac` you're using)

Comment: do you have an example of what you mean? I'm struggling to come up with an example of my own

Comment: @gregghz `val f: Function2[Int, Int, Int] = { case (a, b) => a * b }` <- I gave an explicit type annotation that this should be a function that takes two arguments, but the compiler let me use `case (a, b)` as if I was matching against a tuple. Strictly speaking a "function that takes a Tuple2 as its only argument" and a "function that takes two arguments" are different things, but I guess there's some kind of rule in the compiler that lets you treat them as similar when using `case`

Comment: interesting -- I just verified and that does indeed work for both scala 2 and scala 3. Thanks!